# TypeScript - constructor expression for NaN check

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript we can build constructors with default values like so:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: number = 0) {
        // this.bar is 0 if constructed with no arguments.
    }
}
```

TypeScript generates the following imperative:

```
if(bar === void 0) bar = 0;
```

Is there a way to declare a short-hand syntax, in a similar way to prevent NaN from being assigned?

Essentially I want TypeScript to generate:

```
if(bar === void 0 || isNaN(bar)) bar = 0;
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do that automatically. As you say, the shorthand syntax is a way to assign a default value for a parameter only when it is omitted. If it is included, you'll have to check for undesired values manually. Oh, and `bar === NaN` is always false, use the function `isNaN(bar)` instead.

Comment: @CRice updated to include `isNaN(bar)`

Comment: `Number.isNaN` should be used to check for the `NaN` value.

Comment: @zerkms why `Number.isNaN` vs `isNaN`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN `isNaN(undefined); // true` `Number.isNaN(undefined); // false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially I want TypeScript to generate

You will have to write it yourself:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: number = 0) {
        if (isNaN(bar)) this.bar = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the signature and implemented the check for `undefined` manually?

Comment: @zerkms so that it wasn't spread in two places. Updated to keep as much of original code as possible.

Comment: I just realised, that for the ES2015 target it would not even emit the check for undefined, would it?

Comment: @basarat is there a way to use decorators to check NaN, i.e. `constructor(@CheckNaN value: number) { ... }`